# About jquery / fullcalendar versions incompatibility?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Reading docs https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-8-fullcalendar-with-create-edit-delete-event-exampleexample.html

I try to add fullcalendar into my Laravel 8 /  jQuery 3.5.1 / bootstrap  4.5.3 app.
In this article jquery/3.1.1 and fullcalendar/3.9.0 are used and afetr I added fullcalendar
files in my blade file :

```
@section('scripts')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>

    <script>
        jQuery.noConflict();  //Not to conflict with other scripts
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
```

I got javascript error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.js:1259)
    at __webpack_require__ (fullcalendar.js:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.js:4554)
    at __webpack_require__ (fullcalendar.js:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.js:1759)
    at __webpack_require__ (fullcalendar.js:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.js:12379)
    at __webpack_require__ (fullcalendar.js:35)
    at fullcalendar.js:78
    at fullcalendar.js:81
```

In the article jquery/3.1.1 was used.
Can you say if it versions incompatibility ?

1. To which version of fullcalendar have I to move ?
2. Is the arrtcle above code valid for fullcalendar 4, 5 ?

Thanks!

Comment: The PHP code shown in the article should work with any fullCalendar version. But the frontend code wouldn't work without changes - the newer fullCalendar versions don't use jQuery and the syntax is to set it up is different in various ways. Check the latest fullCalendar documentation for setup details and example code.

Comment: 1) could you  please point from which version fullCalendar dose not use jQuery  ? Anyway I have jQuery and can not remove it  2) could you please give link of similar  example code ?

Comment: The ones you mentioned - 4 and 5 - don't use jQuery. But that doesn't mean you cannot use jQuery in the rest of your page. It's merely that fullCalendar does not depend on it.

Comment: You can find lots of code examples in the fullCalendar documentation and elsewhere online. What specifically do you need an example of? It should be possible for you to convert the code from that tutorial by a) reading the fullCalendar documentation and b) reading the upgrade guides ([here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/upgrading-from-v3) and [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4)) to go from v3 to v5. Try it. If you get stuck, post your new code and explain the problem.

Comment: P.S. fullcalendar 3.9 works perfectly with jQuery 3.5.1 - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/OJVMPVy . It's not clear what you might have done wrong really. From the few details you've shown, I can only guess maybe the `jQuery.noConflict()` is causing a problem - do you have another JS library in your page which actually requires that?